# Why does Andrew Yang want to give people $1,000 per month when that is a relative value?

Tags: united-states

From his apparent [website](https://www.yang2020.com/what-is-freedom-dividend-faq/),

> Andrew Yang is running for President as Democrat in 2020 to implement the Freedom Dividend. This form of UBI that he is proposing for the United States is a set of guaranteed payments of $1,000 per month, or $12,000 per year, to all U.S. citizens over the age of 18. Yes, that means you and everyone you know would get another $1,000/month every month from the U.S. government, no questions asked.

Could somebody explain why he is saying that people will get $1,000 per month, which is a relative amount of money? I mean, it sounds like a decent chunk of money that would help a lot of people out, but isn't that's only *today*? The value of $1,000 dollars will change due to inflation.

For example, Andrew Yang is 44 years old. If a person received a $1,000 per month for that amount of years, by the end of it, the relative value would be, based on some historical estimates of inflation, *5 times less*, i.e. roughly $200 per month in today's money. And as time goes on, the value falls even more.

On top of that, one needs to consider the dynamic effects of the policy itself. It is likely that it will lead to *more* inflation than what has been historically the case. This is a common criticism of his policy, and curiously, Andrew Yang doesn't even deny it himself, e.g. it is stated on his webpage

> It is likely that some companies will increase their prices in response to people having more buying power, and a VAT would also increase prices marginally.

So since inflation would be higher than what we've usually seen, this means that the example above would be even more extreme, and possibly the value of those $1,000 drops even faster.

So why has he based his UBI policy on a relative amount of money when all logic dictates that he needs to use an absolute measure?

For example, there exists many indexes where people calculate prices of common consumer products and use them as a measure of the price level. He could then set his UBI payment to be a fixed percentage of some particular index.

**So, why does he propose doing it this way? What is the advantage?**

Comment: It seems he's campaigning for 2020, we can only speculate what number he'll come up with in 2024.

Comment: I don't understand what is the question here. Many laws have fixed amounts in them, and get periodically revised to be adjusted for inflation.

Comment: @Federico He's asking if Yang has talked about indexing his fund for inflation and how to account for inflation in policies that cause inflation themselves. Seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Federico: A prime example would be the (US) 7th Amendment, which requires jury trials when the disputed amount is more than $20 - which was quite a bit of money when that was written.

Answer (score 9):

Laws on taxation and payments routinely specify absolute rather than relative amounts.

[US Income Tax](https://smartasset.com/taxes/current-federal-income-tax-brackets), [UK Inheritance Tax](https://www.gov.uk/inheritance-tax) and [German Child Benefit](https://www.iamexpat.de/expat-info/social-security/child-benefits-germany-kindergeld) for example. This doesn't mean they will never change, just that the specific level has been chosen and will continue until laws are changed.

This can have the benefit of allowing people to budget more effectively as they know what income they will receive and can calculate their taxes with certainty.

It does have potential downsides such as [fiscal drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_drag) and [services under funding](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/education/education-news/nursery-schools-council-funding-government-closures-mps-debate-lucy-powell-labour-a8754996.html)

Answer (score 2):

**You're not seeing the big picture here.**

UBI is trying to solve multiple problems at once: Giving Americans a social safety net, protecting society against the potential of mass unemployment as automation becomes more and more advanced, (minorly) reducing income inequality, and shaking up the increasing divide between urban and rural in preparation for the digital age.

It's the last that addresses your issue the most. Rather than provide a cost-of-living increase, it gives $1000 all around. Digital doesn't care where you live, so long as you have decent internet, and if you're jobless (due to automation), it also doesn't matter where you live.

Rather than figuring out how to pack 10 million more people into NYC (expensive), people are incentivized towards heading to less expensive rural areas and either telecommute or provide value to rural communities that need more small businesses.

Studies have shown that the more people are moving interstate, the more innovation occurs via cross-pollination.
This is an entirely different economic/geographic model than what we currently have.

I can't claim to know that any deflation will perfectly match inflation, but there are a lot more moving parts (economically) here than you're acknowledging.

Answer (score 0):

When the federal reserve creates money, there's more money chasing the same amount of goods. This makes the price of everything go up.

When Andrew Yang gives out his $1000, he's taking the money [from somewhere](https://www.yang2020.com/policies/value-added-tax/). "This VAT would vary based on the good to which it’s applied, with staples having a lower rate or being excluded, and luxury goods having a higher rate." This means that there is less demand for luxuries that wealthy people buy (like sports cars) and more demand for things that less wealthy people buy (like sedans). In the short run, this means there might be a shortage of sedans and the price of sedans would go up. However, in a dynamic market economy firms will adjust their production to produce more sedans and bid the price down to try to capture the new volume of people wanting affordable cars. Eventually, the price will go down. Likewise the price of sports cars will go down as the wealthy aren't able to buy sports cars and the market produces too many, until firms adjust their production to match demand better.

So prices will change as money is redistributed from one group to another and eventually level out as the economy shifts what it produces to match the demands of the new distribution of money to people. The changes in prices caused by the universal basic income are real changes in the economy and signals to firms to change their production, not mere inflation.

The $1000 should be indexed to inflation, since central banks will still cause inflation by printing money, but it's very reasonable to give out the money at a fixed rate.

Comment: While I agree with the argument, using sports cars vs station wagons as an example is just wrong.  The most common sports car in the US - the Mazda Miata/MX5 - has a MSRP starting at $25,730, which is significantly cheaper than most of the few station wagons available in the US today, and way cheaper than the SUVs and dual cab pickups that people buy instead.

Comment: @jamesqf lol changed to sedan. I'm clearly not a car guy

Comment: Doesn't really work with sedans, either, since most actual sports cars are relatively expensive.  You might try Hundai (cheap sedan) vs BMW (expensive sedan).

Comment: Or you might try something you're familiar with instead of cars, as you stated yourself: you're not a car guy.